# SQLite query for may not be in condition

Tags: sqlite

I've a table with following information.

```
AreaDescription     AD
------------------
Processing1         BB
Geology         BC
pilot           BB
```

Need dynamic way to find if there's no match in AD for a given set ('BC','G','S') it returns all the records, otherwise just return the ones which matches in the given set ('BC','G','S')

```
select * from tblArea where AreaDescription like '%o%' and (AD in ('BC','G','S') or 1=1)
```

I was trying the above SQL, where it contains

> (AD in ('BC','G','S') or 1=1)

expressing if AD has value in ('BC','G','S') then return those or else return everything as per 1=1 condition.

But this doesn't work as I thought it works.

Here I get all rows not only which contains only 'BC', so I guess the OR condition is not correct way?

Is there a way I can do this? using SWITCH ?

Comment: SqlLite don't have any procedural language. So simply you can not do it using simple procedure. You have to join or union both evaluations. But you can simply do it programmically in your code.

Comment: `1=1` is always true, and if you combine that with another condition using `OR`, then of course and obviously that other conditions outcome doesn’t matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine two queries, and use EXISTS in the second one to check if the first did match any records:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblArea
WHERE AreaDescription LIKE '%o%'
  AND AD IN ('BC', 'G', 'S')
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM tblArea
WHERE AreaDescription LIKE '%o%'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblArea
                  WHERE AreaDescription LIKE '%o%'
                    AND AD IN ('BC', 'G', 'S'))
```